# jQuery function duplication. How can I make this shorter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplication

You can check page here: http://jsfiddle.net/7JhjN/

Basicly, there is a hell of duplication going on and I don't like this. I am sure there is something wrong since it's not a correct programming logic.

How can I shorten this function?

**The system works like this:**
1. There are 6x select boxes. (option values are the same)
2. There are 6x divs for output.
3. Whenever a select box value gets changed, image in target div gets changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about this:

HTML:

```
<select class='item_early' name="item_early1" data-id="1"><option value="0"></option></select>
<select class='item_early' name="item_early2" data-id="2"> <option value="0"></option></select>
<select class='item_early' name="item_early3" data-id="3"> <option value="0"></option></select>
<select class='item_early' name="item_early4" data-id="4"> <option value="0"></option></select>

<div id="result_item_early1"></div>
<div id="result_item_early2"></div>
<div id="result_item_early3"></div>
<div id="result_item_early4"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.item_early').change( function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  var id = $(this).data('id');

  $('#result_item_early'+id).html('<img src="http://www.sobafire.com/themes/default/images/loading.gif">');
  $('#result_item_early'+id).load('http://www.sobafire.com/ajax.php?ajaxType=ITEM&itemID=' + value);
});
```

Comment: Nice answer, clearly the right way.  Maybe `name` should be `id`?

Comment: @Hogan Thanks, a little change to the HTML always end up simplifying my javascript

Answer (score 2):

Your problem, you have something that looks like this:

```
$('#item_early1').change( function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    //directly set loading value as html
    $('#result_item_early1').html('<img src="http://www.sobafire.com/themes/default/images/loading.gif">');

    //change image url source from server (expected return value is something like <img src="" />
    $('#result_item_early1').load('http://www.sobafire.com/ajax.php?ajaxType=ITEM&itemID=' + value);

});
```

And you repeat for the different constants.

The answer is replace the constants with variable names like this then put it in a function:

```
function doit(itemID,resultID) {
  $(itemID).change( function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      //directly set loading value as html
      $(resultID).html('<img src="http://www.sobafire.com/themes/default/images/loading.gif">');

      //change image url source from server (expected return value is something like <img src="" />
      $(resultID).load('http://www.sobafire.com/ajax.php?ajaxType=ITEM&itemID=' + value);
  });
}
```

Then call that function for all your constants:

```
doit('#item_early1','#result_item_early1');
doit('#item_early2','#result_item_early2');
doit('#item_early3','#result_item_early3');
doit('#item_early4','#result_item_early4');
doit('#item_early5','#result_item_early5');
doit('#item_early6','#result_item_early6');
```

Comment: Making functions was something I had in my mind, but I would have to be calling each function seperatedly. I was mostly interested in a simple function, which would retrieve all the data and output accordingly without having to edit function calls every time. The post ShankarSangoli made was what I was looking for, however, I appreciate your comment and thank you for your guidance. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code by using starts with attribute selector.

```
$('select[name^="item_early"]').change( function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var value = $this.val();
    var $resultDiv = $('#result_' + $this.attr('name'));
    //directly set loading value as html
    $resultDiv.html('<img src="http://www.sobafire.com/themes/default/images/loading.gif">');

    //change image url source from server (expected return value is something like <img src="" />
    $resultDiv.load('http://www.sobafire.com/ajax.php?ajaxType=ITEM&itemID=' + value);

});
```

Working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7JhjN/4/)

Comment: hmmm... does this really simplify the code?  Seems much more complex to me -- this is a user that did not know how to make a function.

Comment: @Hogan - This is a simple and best solution for this kind of scenario. OP is looking to shorten the code. If OP has any doubt I am there to answer OP's questions.

Comment: Not sure it is the best -- I expect mine is faster (but not much -- just the difference between a match on `select[name^="item_early"]` and 6 id lookups).

Comment: Not always -- what if you had a new pair of drop down and result named `item_late1` and `result_item_late1`.  Mine only requires one new line and yours requires being re-written.  In any case Bassam's answer is better than both of ours.  Mine is clearer to a new javascript programmer, yours is slightly shorter.

Comment: My answer is as per OP's markup. You can think of many such what ifs.

Comment: Thank you alot. This was what I was looking for. @Hogan; I know how to make a function.